# How can I automatically send commands and capture output with a program that is still running?

Tags: bash, scripting

I am running a program that accepts commands and provides terminal output, but does not terminate once it has finished executing a command, and instead waits for the next command. I want to use a bash script to read lines from a file, send those lines as commands to the program, and then write the program's output to a file.

I've been trying something like this:

```
program
while read line
do
    $line # I want this sent as a command to the program
    $variable=(`another command to program`)
    echo $variable >> $2
done <$1
```

But this fails at line 3; the command is not sent to the program.

Comment: You should probably be using expect or pexpect, not bash.

Comment: ...that said, if you really _do_ want to use bash for this, see the `coproc` keyword.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In bash 4.x:

```
coproc program
while read -u "${COPROC[0]}" line; do
  echo "something" >&"${COPROC[1]}"
done
```

Older shells can (somewhat more painfully) be made to do this with named pipes.